# custom facebook share button

Tags: php, facebook, share

I want to share my website articles on facebook (content,image,title)!

but facebook doesn't detect correct image.

in this case I put an static image URL.

this is my code:

```
<li>
    <a id="buttton"  href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&amp;p[title]=<?php echo $title;?>&amp;p[summary]=<?php echo $summary;?>&amp;p[url]=<?php echo urlencode($url);?>&amp;p[images][0]=http://www.example.com/images/report/daily_report/KNDR/image(2).jpg" onclick="javascript:window.open(this.href, '', 'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=no,scrollbars=no,height=400,width=600'); return false;">
        <img src="<?php echo base_url()?>media/images/share.png" alt=""/>
    </a>
</li>
```

Comment: facebook dosnt share my presented image!

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can use facebook javascript sdk. First add FB Js SDK to your code (please refer to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript)

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function(){
FB.init({
    appId: 'xxxxx', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true }); 
};
(function(d, debug){var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    if(d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; 
    js.async = true;js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all" + (debug ? "/debug" : "") + ".js";
    ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);}(document, /*debug*/ false));
function postToFeed(title, desc, url, image){
var obj = {method: 'feed',link: url, picture: 'http://www.url.com/images/'+image,name: title,description: desc};
function callback(response){}
FB.ui(obj, callback);
}
```

So when you want to share something

```
<a href="someurl.com/some-article" data-image="article-1.jpg" data-title="Article Title" data-desc="Some description for this article" class="btnShare">Share</a>
```

And finally JS to handle click:

```
$('.btnShare').click(function(){
elem = $(this);
postToFeed(elem.data('title'), elem.data('desc'), elem.prop('href'), elem.data('image'));

return false;
});
```

Comment: This does not work, you get postToFeed is undefined.

Comment: it works great, are you sure you've added the function postToFeed? Can you provide your code @jetlej

Comment: Superb!!. This worked. I need to dynamically change the data and this is the solution

Comment: Yes @DragosRizescu

Comment: I got the error `elem is undefined`. Needed to change the second line to `var elem = $(this);`

Comment: Can any one provide example of this functionality

Answer (score 12):

This solution is using javascript to open a new window when a user clicks on your custom share button.

HTML:

```
<a href="#" onclick="share_fb('http://urlhere.com/test/55d7258b61707022e3050000');return false;" rel="nofollow" share_url="http://urlhere.com/test/55d7258b61707022e3050000" target="_blank">

  //using fontawesome
  <i class="uk-icon-facebook uk-float-left"></i>
    Share
</a>
```

and in your javascript file. note window.open params are (url, dialogue title, width, height)

```
function share_fb(url) {
  window.open('https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u='+url,'facebook-share-dialog',"width=626, height=436")
}
```

Answer (score 9):

The best way is to use your code and then store the image in OG tags in the page you are linking to, then Facebook will pick them up.

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Facebook Open Graph Demo">
<meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/main-image.png">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Example Website">
<meta property="og:description" content="Here is a nice description">
```

You can find documentation to OG tags and how to use them with share buttons [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button)

Comment: Can you send me a link and I can look at it?

Comment: I added all as you said but it did't worked until I added solution provided by @artuc. The project is on localhost so I'm unable to provide you url as of now.

Comment: It won't work on localhost as when you share the link facebooks own servers will check that url for the meta tags.

Answer (score 8):

Well, I use this method on my site:

```
<a class="share-btn" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?app_id=[your_app_id]&sdk=joey&u=[full_article_url]&display=popup&ref=plugin&src=share_button" onclick="return !window.open(this.href, 'Facebook', 'width=640,height=580')">
```

Works perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

Given that we are in a php code context and the variable `$url` contains the link the user wants to share, you can try this to use a custom image :

```
<a class="facebook-share-button" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=<?php echo urlencode($url); ?>" target="_blank"><img src="/img/facebook-share-button.png" /></a>
```

or this for just plain text :

```
<a class="facebook-share-button" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=<?php echo urlencode($url); ?>" target="_blank">share</a>
```

You can also style the link purely with css.

The html code :

```
<a class="facebook-share-button" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=<?php echo urlencode($url); ?>" target="_blank"></a>
```

The css code :

```
.facebook-share-button {
    background-image: url("/img/facebook-share-button.png");
    display: inline-block;
    height: 32px;
    width: 32px;
}

.facebook-share-button:active,
.facebook-share-button:focus,
.facebook-share-button:hover {
    background-image: url("/img/facebook-share-button-hover.png");
}
```

Comment: good answer, i would just add a target="_blank" or it closes the sharing window after the share

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do something like...

```
...
<head>
...
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId            : 'your-app-id', // you need to create an facebook app
      autoLogAppEvents : true,
      xfbml            : true,
      version          : 'v3.3'
    });
  };
</script>
<script async defer src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
...
<button id="share-btn"></button>
<!-- load jquery -->
<script>
    $('#share-btn').on('click', function () {
        FB.ui({
            method: 'share',
            href: location.href, // Current url
        }, function (response) { });
    });
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Include the facebook button on the page which you want to share

```
<a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://trial.com/news.php?newsid=<?php echo $content; ?>"> 

                    <img src="http://trial/new_img/facebook_link.png" style=" border: 1px solid #d9d9d9; box-shadow: 0 4px 7px 0 #a5a5a5; padding: 5px;" title="facebook_link" alt="facebook_link" />

                    </a>
```

Comment: this is a browser dependent solution, if the user's browser setting is set to open links in new tab, then there is no way it would pop up as new window. except if you make a js function for it.

http://stackoverflow.com/a/32158402/1418771